# Get datagrid rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid, visibility, datagridrowheader

How can I get the list of rows in the DataGrid? Not the bound items, but the 
`DataGridRows` list.

I need to control the visibility of these rows and it's only possible to control it as a `DataGridRow` and not as a data object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

You can get the row using [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx). This should work -

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                               .ContainerFromIndex(i);
}
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that when virtualization is on (which it is by default), you will get `null` for rows that weren't created. This means that you won't be able to iterate through all the rows in a single run, unless you set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your DataGrid - but this may cause your grid to have poor performance.

Comment: Hello, how can I do that in UWP?

Comment: I got value null exception , how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend defining a Style for `DataGridRow` that will have its Visibility bound to whether it should be displayed or not. Just iterating through the rows won't be enough, as I mentioned in @RV1987's answer.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ...}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:**

What you bind to depends on where you hold the information of whether or not you should display the row. For example, if each data object in your bound collection has a `bool ShouldBeDisplayed` property, you would have something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />

        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=ShouldBeDisplayed, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Binding of what?This is not a uielemnt...can u be more specific?

Comment: Does not work sorry...
I Add this property:
I try this:
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding  Path=ShouldBeDisplayed}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

and add this property to the object:
        public Visibility ShouldBeDisplayed { get; set; }

Whats wrong?thank u!

Comment: @user196625 Did you actually set the value of the property for each item?

Comment: yes..I set it by clicking a button..maybe it is not set immediatlly?
There is a binding i check it but in running time when I change it nothing happened.

Comment: If it's not set when the control is bound, you'll also have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the objects.