# How can i get all rows of C# Wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to get all DataGridRows in DataGrid?
like

```
foreach (DataGridRow dr in postQueue.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr.GetIndex());
    }
```

of cource wrong, because i need every DataGridRow element, not struct.

```
for (int i = 0; i < postQueue.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)postQueue.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                           .ContainerFromIndex(i);
                row.Header = i.ToString();
            }
```

Throws 
`row was null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get datagrid rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762310/get-datagrid-rows)

Comment: There are no `DataGridRow` containers for items that are not currently visible due to the UI virtualization that the `DataGrid` implements. You can turn this off but it comes with a performance penalty. Why do you need access to the containers?

Comment: I wanted to add indexes automatically to the left side of datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you bind your DataGrid to an ObservableCollection?

XAML :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourList}" >
...
</DataGrid>
```

MVVM :

```
private ObservableCollection<T> yourList = new ObservableCollection<Hole>();
public ObservableCollection<T> YourList
{
    get { return yourList; }
    set
    {
        this.yourList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("YourList");
    }
}
```

then to get it just do :

```
foreach (T element in this.YourList)
{
   ...
}
```